# RIA services presentation model with 1-many or many-many relationships

Tags: wcf-ria-services, presentation-model

I'm trying to get a presentation model (discussed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/deepm/archive/2009/11/20/wcf-ria-services-presentation-model-explained.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707347(VS.91).aspx)) working in RIA. All the examples I can find are simple, flat data entities with no 1-many or many-many relationships, which are what I can't get working - specifically, on updates and inserts into associative relationships.

Queries I can get working fine - I have my presentation classes marked up with Association attributes (and Include attributes, where appropriate), and I have a good understanding about how data is loaded into the client side and maintained there as entities. I also have inserts of new entities covered. However, I'm experiencing the following problems. For the following examples, assume we have simple Album and Artist entities, where an Album has a single artist and an Artist can have zero to many albums. Both have a Name property.

- On the client side, if I do myArtist.Albums.Add(anAlbum) or myArtist.Albums.Remove(anAlbum), nothing happens. HasChanges returns false. (Note that myArtist and anAlbum were obtained solely in code by loading the entities and iterating to get references to specific entities: I'm not doing anything in UI or with DomainDataSources yet, just dinking around).
- If I update the Name on an Artist and SubmitChanges, when the Update method gets called on the server, the Albums collection is null.

Does anyone have any suggestions, or can you point me to an example that uses more complex objects?

**EDIT** (keeping the above for posterity): Alright, it appears that the second issue (a reference to an entity or a collection of entities showing as null when Update gets called on the server) exists because the child entites aren't marked as Changed and so they aren't being serialized and sent back. I know you can force that to happen by using [Composition] and I have gotten it to work that way, but this is not a compositional relationship and I want both entities to be "top-level" entities. How can I mark an entity as changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my [Association] attributes weren't correctly defined. I didn't realize that the association's Name property has to be the same on both sides of the association. When the names are the same and you do a build, the generated code on the client uses a different constructor for the EntityCollection used by the "parent" to refer to the "children" than it does if the associations aren't set up right. The new constructor takes callbacks that do a little bit of extra handling when you call Add and Remove on the collection - specifically, they take the child entity you are adding or removing and modify the property on it that refers to its parent so that everything remains in sync: the collection you removed the object from, the collection you added it to, and the object's reference to its parent.